# How do I read the Firebase Remote Config template version from Android?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-remote-config

On Firebase Remote Config console I see `Config - Version 26` where 26 is the template version of the config.

How do I read that version from Android?

I am using `implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-config:19.0.3"`

Answer (score 2):

While the straightforward way how to read the template config version in the app is missing, we implemented this work-around:

We have defined an extra remote config parameter and filled its value with the config version. As it is an ordinal firebase parameter, it can be accessed by the app. The drawback of this solution is clear - don't forget to increment this parameter value within each remote config template change.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the dependency

```
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config'
```

And then in your activity:

```
public void checkForVersionUpdate() {
        FirebaseRemoteConfig firebaseRemoteConfig;
        firebaseRemoteConfig = FirebaseRemoteConfig.getInstance();
        FirebaseRemoteConfigSettings configSettings = new FirebaseRemoteConfigSettings.Builder().setMinimumFetchIntervalInSeconds(3600).build();
        firebaseRemoteConfig.setConfigSettingsAsync(configSettings);
        firebaseRemoteConfig.fetchAndActivate().addOnSuccessListener(aVoid -> {
            double latestAppVersion = firebaseRemoteConfig.getDouble("build_version");
            if (latestAppVersion > getCurrentBuildVersion()) {
                //enter what needs to be done if your the version differs
               } else {
                //up to date
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: `FirebaseRemoteConfig: No value of type 'Double' exists for parameter key 'build_version'.`

Answer (score 0):

> On Firebase Remote Config console I see Config - Version 26

That's the [template version](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/templates). That version increments every time you publish config changes in the console.

> How do I read that version from Android?

There's no way to read the template version from the Android SDK. In other words, there's no getter for the template version alongside the [getters for other metadata](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/remoteconfig/FirebaseRemoteConfigInfo).

That said, from the code sample, it looks like the question might be rephrased "How do I target configuration to my app's version?". You'd do that using the "app version" [targeting condition](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/parameters#condition_rule_types). The Android SDK sends the app version when fetching configuration. Any configuration gated by that condition will only be returned if the version matches the condition.

Comment: Thank you for also confirming my assumption that there isn't a way to read that. Although I appreciate your suggestion, it is a solution to a different problem, not the one I'm asking